# Using rubyzip error - no such file to load -- zip/zip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rubyzip

I know there is another thread on this subject but I still face this problem even after using all solutions. Is there any other way to generate zip files? Can i use Ubuntu system commands?

I did

```
 gem install rubyzip
```

I have

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip/zip'
```

in my controller

But i still get the same error - no such file to load -- zip/zip
I tried with both ruby 1.8.7 and ruby 1.9.2 with rails 3.0.5 on Ubuntu

Could you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am in the same situation. Thanks

Comment: Nope i am still in search of the solution, it works in irb shell but not with rails.

Comment: Make sure you have `gem 'rubyzip'` in your Gemfile. Also, it depends what functionality of rubyzip you're using, but you may need to use `require 'zip/zipfilesystem'` in addition to what you have above.

Comment: gem 'rubyzip', :require => 'zip/zip' in Gemfile worked :) Finally! Thanks Erik

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After spending lot of time, I finally figured out the missing part. When using the `rubyzip` gem, I also had to require `zip/zip`.

Add this to your Gemfile

`gem 'rubyzip', :require => 'zip/zip'`

Just adding `gem 'rubyzip` did not work for me.

Comment: did work for me after I changed to be ... :require => 'zip' in Gemfile, and in application code to require 'zip'

Answer (score 23):

I fixed this problem by specifying gem version 0.9.9 in Gemfile:

```
gem 'rubyzip',  "~> 0.9.9"
```

Using rubyzip (1.0.0) caused an error. There's a note about this on [rubyzip gihub](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#important-note):

> Rubyzip interface changed!!! No need to do require "zip/zip" and Zip
>   prefix in class names removed. If you have issues with any third-party
>   gems what required rubyzip you can use next temporary fix:
>
> ```
> # Place this line before your library or on the head of your Gemfile
> gem 'rubyzip', '< 1.0.0'
> ```

Comment: interesting how this question was asked long before the 1.0.0 was released

Comment: Thank you! This helped me with the error caused when I added the gtfs gem: `/home/kobilya/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/gtfs-0.2.2/lib/gtfs/source.rb:3:in 'require': cannot load such file -- zip/zip (LoadError)`

Answer (score 17):

Building on @eagor's answer, if you'd like to use rubyzip >= 1.0 but need backwards compatibility add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'zip-zip'
```

Saves updating legacy code.

Answer (score 7):

When upgrading rubyzip to 1.0.0 change `require 'zip/zip'` to `require 'zip'`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19506372/567399

Answer (score 3):

Also make sure that your unzipping process uses:

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(self.data) do |zipfile|
```

not

```
Zip::Zipfile.open(self.data) do |zipfile|
```

The capital F on ZipFile makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who has problems with `rubyzip` and comes across this thread: remember that you can always shell out to an external command-line zip utility. There are a number of free command-line utilities which you can find through Google. Once you install your command-line zip program of choice and make sure it is on the system path, just use backticks to drive it from within Ruby. Of course, this won't work for web applications which are running on Heroku, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was needed to change from

```
Zip::File.open(...)
```

to

```
Zip::ZipFile.open(...)
```

of course I need to also add this to Gemfile:

```
gem 'rubyzip', :require => 'zip/zip'
```