# How to access 'zip' gem (or 'rubyzip') in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zip, archive

I must be missing something totally obvious but I can't seem to get the ['zip'](http://rubygems.org/gems/zip) gem to work.  I've installed it with rubygems just like I've done with many other gems.  Rubygem says it's there but yet when I try to require it, Ruby says it's not there.  I'm experiencing the same problem on both Windows and Linux.  Here's a Linux session (extra output removed for brevity):

```
~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
~$ gem list z
~$ sudo gem install zip 
Successfully installed zip-2.0.2
~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'zip/zip'
LoadError: no such file to load -- zip/zip
        from (irb):1:in `require'
        from (irb):1
        from :0
```

And a Windows session:

```
C:\> ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i386-mingw32]
C:\> gem list z
C:\> gem install zip
Successfully installed zip-2.0.2
C:\> irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'zip/zip'
LoadError: no such file to load -- zip/zip
        from (irb):1:in `require'
        from (irb):1
```

I'm thinking perhaps there's some underlying dependency that 'zip' needs but I haven't found anything about that in the docs.

I've also had the same lack of success with ['rubyzip'](http://rubygems.org/gems/rubyzip)  It seems that perhaps 'zip' and 'rubyzip' are forks?

Any ideas?  Or if there's a better gem out there for archiving, I'd love to hear about it.  [The choice of zip archiving gems is confusing.](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=rubyzip)  The gem ['Zippy'](http://rubygems.org/gems/zippy) looks good but it requires 'zip' so I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this.

```
gem install rubyzip2
```

then

```
irb> require 'rubygems'
#=>  true
irb> require 'zip/zip'
#=>  true
# you can also require 'zip/zipfilesystem'
```

Comment: same problem.  I've also tried `require 'rubyzip'`, `require 'rubyzip2'` and dozens of other combinations in my irb test.

Comment: did you run `require 'rubygems'` first?

Comment: Ahh, your update came through now.  That passes the irb test.  Thanks!

Comment: rubyzip2 is now deprecated, so you should use rubyzip instead

Comment: [People with this problem can alos look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997539/using-rubyzip-error-no-such-file-to-load-zip-zip)

Answer (score 2):

With rubyzip 1.1.0 the correct require is

require 'zip'

As per the docs at http://rubydoc.info/gems/rubyzip/1.1.0