# rails 3 - LoadError (cannot load such file -- zip/zip)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rubyzip

I'm using rubyzip to zip a csv file so uses can download it. This works perfectly in development mode. But when I tried zipping the file on the production server (rackspace) I received the error: LoadError (cannot load such file -- zip/zip). Is it a path issue? Anyone know a fix?

The error is being called in my code on this line: require 'zip/zip'

I've tried the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997539/using-rubyzip-error-no-such-file-to-load-zip-zip), but it didn't help.

Comment: Not related with this question but in case someone will have the same problem as me -
with versions > 1.0 you should `require 'zip'` not 'zip/zip'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem: error thrown on "require 'zip/zip'" code, and the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997539/using-rubyzip-error-no-such-file-to-load-zip-zip) also did not help.

After a long research I found that the problem was that my "require 'zip/zip'" statement was done in a separate

```
lib/exporters/package_exporter.rb
```

file, and for some reason "require" statements are not handled in "lib" folder in production by default.

When I moved "require 'zip/zip'" to the beginning of my

```
app/controllers/packages_controller.rb
```

the problem was solved!

Comment: Can you show me an example? I'm having the same problem and can't fix it at all.

Answer (score 31):

I fixed this problem by specifying gem version 0.9.9 in Gemfile:

```
gem 'rubyzip',  "~> 0.9.9"
```

Using rubyzip (1.0.0) caused an error.

Comment: Or you can also add `gem 'zip-zip'` which provides backward compatibility.

Answer (score 20):

When upgrading rubyzip to 1.0.0 change `require 'zip/zip'` to `require 'zip'`.

Comment: I think this is the winner

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem after adding roo to a Rails project.

Roo needed the new interface, something else (some other gem) was using the old interface - so most of these answers didn't work (couldn't lower the version of rubyzip, rubyzip2 is deprecated, didn't have require zip/zip in my project).

What worked for me was cassio-s-cabral's answer referring to the [rubyzip github](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) page.

```
gem 'rubyzip', '>= 1.0.0' # will load new rubyzip version
gem 'zip-zip' # will load compatibility for old rubyzip API.
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue with active_support, just added the 'zip' gem to my Gemfile and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

I'm use **rubyzip2** gem to fix this problem

```
gem 'rubyzip2'
```

Answer (score 2):

what work for me was to install 2 gems: 
`gem install rubyzip 
 gem install zip`

and in the script put 
    `require 'rubygems' 
require 'zip/zip'`

Answer (score 0):

In their [github page](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip) explains what to do.

Rubyzip interface changed!!! No need to do require "zip/zip" and Zip 
    prefix in class names removed.

If you have issues with any third-party gems what required old 
    version of rubyzip you can use next workaround:

```
gem 'rubyzip', '>= 1.0.0' # will load new rubyzip version
gem 'zip-zip' # will load compatibility for old rubyzip API.
```