# LoadError: cannot load such file -- zip/zip when running any rails command after upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I've just upgraded to rails 6, and I'm getting the following when running `rails app:update`

```
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- zip/zip
/home/ben/code/app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ben/code/app/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've updated all the gems and it's bundling and updating the gems, the gemfile.lock looks OK as well.

Here is the backtrace:

```
Error:[rake --tasks] rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- zip/zip
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/axlsx-1.3.6/lib/axlsx.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
/home/ben/code/app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/home/ben/code/BusinessCloudEssential/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/home/ben/code/app/bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
```

Here is the application.rb

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
require 'net/http'
require 'csv'

module RailsUpgrade
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.0

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.

    config.time_zone = 'London'
    #WARNING: This changes the way times are stored in the database (not recommended)
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

    config.log_level = :debug
    config.enable_dependency_loading = true
    config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')

    config.assets.enabled = true
    config.assets.version = '1.0'

    config.filter_parameters << :password
    config.filter_parameters << :password_confirmation
    config.filter_parameters << :card_number
    config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation, :card_number]

    # config.middleware.use 'CatchJsonParseErrors'
  end
end
```

Last time I ran `rails app:update` was when I updated to Rails 5.2 earlier today. So not sure what the issue is.

Thanks.

Comment: I just googled your error message, and the top result led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18630233/1954610). Does that seem relevant to you? Are you using the `rubyzip` gem, and did you also just upgrade it? Are you specifying `require 'zip/zip'` anywhere in your code? If so, does replacing this with `require 'zip'` resolve the error?

Comment: @TomLord tried that, looked for `require 'zip/zip'` and it's nowhere in my codebase, so I installed a gem called `zip-zip` and that worked

Answer (score 3):

You are using `axlsx` version `1.3.6`, which includes [this line: `require 'zip/zip'`](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/077a9d56728b4a235c4f07a854801a298220c55c/lib/axlsx.rb#L26). That's what your error message is pointing to:

```
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/axlsx-1.3.6/lib/axlsx.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
```

However, I suspect that you've *also* inadvertently upgraded the `rubyzip` gem to `v1.0.0+` - where the API has changed, and you now only need to `require 'zip'`, (**NOT** `require 'zip/zip'`).

There are a few solutions, such as what's mentioned on [the project README](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip#important-note) or in [this similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12079291/1954610):

1. Downgrade `rubyzip` back to `v0.x`.
2. Upgrade `axlsx`.
3. Add `gem 'zip-zip'` to your `Gemfile`.