# Error in HEROKU app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

I push my ruby on rails application to heroku and it was not working and I can not find the error

```
2013-08-29T14:52:50.796180+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-08-29T14:52:57.232554+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 9304 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2013-08-29T14:53:00.449895+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-08-29T14:53:00.449501 #2]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906312+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': no such file to load -- zip/zip (LoadError)
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906312+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906312+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906492+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906492+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/axlsx-1.3.6/lib/axlsx.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906492+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906492+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906492+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906492+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.2/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906654+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906745+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906745+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.906745+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:4:in `require'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.907002+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.907337+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.907337+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.907337+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `new'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.907444+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.907581+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.907581+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.907683+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.907771+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.907917+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.907917+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.908057+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `load'
2013-08-29T14:53:05.908057+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:19:in `<main>'
2013-08-29T14:53:07.333561+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-08-29T14:53:07.347096+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-08-29T14:54:31.437596+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path=/api/GetAllOrdersListCustomer host=xbmonster-dev2.herokuapp.com fwd="181.55.123.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-08-29T14:54:48.207186+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path=/api/mobile/storelist.json host=xbmonster-dev2.herokuapp.com fwd="181.55.123.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: You seem to be missing `zip/zip`. Possibly related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997539/using-rubyzip-error-no-such-file-to-load-zip-zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, the gem of rubyzip was updated in heroku but in my local system not only change the gem version and delete the version that was on heroku

gem "rubyzip", "0.9.9"