How to specify `require` in the `.gemspec` file?
In the Gemfile, I do this:
gem 'rubyzip', '>= 2.3', require: 'zip'

How can I do the same in the .gemspec file? Now, I have this line over there:
s.add_runtime_dependency 'rubyzip', '>= 2.3'

What do I change?

That's all you need to add to the gemspec. If you want to require this in your gem you would place that in lib/mygem.rb. Usually the require option for bundler is reserved for libraries with a different name than the gem. Using your example the gem is called rubyzip but the main file is zip.rb thus gem 'rubyzip', require: 'zip', this says download rubyzip but then require 'zip'

@engineersmnky apparently, require "zip" doesn't work in my code, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6259250/187141

@engineersmnky the rubyzip is installed (via the .gemspec file) and require 'zip' doesn't work

Since you haven't posted any code or error it is difficult to help but I can tell you this is exactly how it works. Take for example the caxlsx gem Gemspec, and require 'zip'
